# transactionReceipt.gasUsed is bigger than the value obtained using gasleft() in smart contract

Tags: testing, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to get the gas used in a transaction in solidity this way:

```
function handleOp(UserOperation calldata op) public {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();

        ....do things...
        uint256 gasPrice = tx.gasprice;
        uint256 endGas = gasleft();
        uint256 gasUsed = startGas - endGas; <----- here
        uint256 totalGas = gasUsed.mul(gasPrice);

        _refundExecutor(totalGas.add(gasConsumedExecution).add(gasConsumedValidation), op.sender);
        
    }
```

gasUsed here is 28553

in my testsuit I have:

```
  const tx = await executorToEntryPoint.handleOp(userOperation)
    const rec = await tx.wait();
    console.log(rec.gasUsed) //72957n

    const executorBalanceAfterTransaction = await provider.getBalance(executor.address)
    console.log("executorBalanceAfterTransaction",executorBalanceAfterTransaction)
    expect(executorBalanceBeforeTransaction).equal(executorBalanceAfterTransaction) <--- failing
```

here gasUsed is 72957

anyone has idea why???